# Bake makes animation stop

Tags: animation, export

I've been working on making my model do stuff, walk, attack, salute, but to export the animation you have to bake, at least that's the only thing that worked for me with PDX, I tried exporting normally but it will fight me and I've come to believe, due to the amount of tutorials that say baking is a must, that it wouldn't end how I'd like if I could do it without baking.

https://www.mediafire.com/folder/giujb9qrhou13/Iron_Golem

That file has the blender folder with my model, the texture file is an old one so it doesn't really matter

Comment: you've given the action to the mesh but you need to give your action to the armature

Comment: Question, what does that mean, this is quite literally my first animation, how would I assign an action to an armature? Its under its subcategory so I thought it was linked but if its not I'm lost there

Comment: open a Dope Sheet window, switch it from Dope Sheet mode to Action Editor mode, select the armature and in the actions dropdown panel of the Dope Sheet select the action, also select the mesh and remove it with the X

Comment: Where are you seeing the option to select the armature and a dropdown panel? I'm looking but my action editor only has  the bones as options to select

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have given the action to the mesh while it should actually be given to the armature if I judge by the tracks name (these are actions for bones as you can see). So try that, select the armature, open the *Dope Sheet* editor, switch it to *Action Editor*, in the actions dropdown panel select the action, it will make the armature move:

[image]

You can remove the action from the mesh: Select the mesh, and click on the  X button next to the action name.

Comment: Thank you so much, I looked into what you were saying, and after a lot of head smashing, realized what the heck you were talking about, thanks for helping me out, I've been banging my head against this for a pretty minute now